# What is the differences between とうとう and ついに? ついに、とうとう違う

Tags: meaning, words, nuances, adverbs

I was reading from japanese language forum to find the differences between とうとうandついに
They give this examples:

1. とうとう誰も来なかった。
2. ついに誰も来なかった。

Both とうとうand ついにcan be used in that sentence, but the forum website said that ついに a lil bit exaggerated.

I can't understand the meaning of this "exaggerated"

If anyone understand, can you help me to explain it, and tell me the differences nuance between this two adverbs? Thank you so much.